# should a db in simple recovery mode have logs truncated prior to backup, after backup or not at all?

Tags: sql-server-2005

should a sql server db in simple recovery mode have logs truncated prior to backup, after backup or not at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [simple recovery mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191164%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), your transaction log won't grow larger than the amount of log space required by your largest concurrent transactions.  Therefore in a well-behaved system, there is no need to truncate the log on each backup.

However, if there is a chance that some expensive (perhaps ad-hoc) queries will use a lot of log space, you might recover some disk space by truncating the log occasionally.

Comment: Truncating the log just marks Recoverable VLFs as Reusable. This happens automatically in simple recovery model. You seem to be using "truncate" and "shrink" interchangeably.